# How to create a backup of an POSTGRES DB using bash?

Tags: bash, postgresql

How to create a backup of an POSTGRES DB using bash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
pg_dump -U some_user_name -f dump.file -Fc database_name
```

That's all.

If you need to authenticate with password - use [pgpass file](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/libpq-pgpass.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use [pg_dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/app-pgdump.html).

Comment: I have difficulties including the username and password with pg_dump

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should add an scheduled job to crontab to be executed daily. The following will create a gzipped sql file with timestamp. SQL dumps otherwise could be very big.

```
pg_dump database_name | gzip -c > ~/backup/postgres/database_name-`/bin/date +%Y%m%d-%H%M`.sql.gz
```